# Changing DataType of cell to Double

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm using OpenXML to create Microsoft Excel file. I'm trying to insert a double type variable (Example : 4.987456789) into the Excel using

```
Cell cell = new Cell()
{
    CellReference = "A2",
    DataType = CellValues.String,
    CellValue = new CellValue(Convert.ToString(value))
};
```

But, when the cell is being made, it's in text form and Excel says "The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe." How can format the cell to insert double?

Edit : 
Sorry, It's double? type and I follow this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cellvalue%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: DataType = CellValues.Double perhaps?

Comment: Nooo.'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues' does not contain a definition for 'Double'

Comment: Maybe DataType = CellValues.Number

Comment: Noo.... It told me (local variable)double? Error : The best overloaded method match for 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(string)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: Only change `DataType` value and keep passing `string` -instead of `Double`- to `CellValue` constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `CellValues.Number` works fine for me, for example :

```
double? value = 4.9874567891;
Cell cell2 = new Cell()
{
    CellReference = "A2",
    DataType = CellValues.Number,
    CellValue = new CellValue(Convert.ToString(value))
};
```

Double value printed to excel without the warning you got.

Comment: I don't know OpenXML or C# but it seems odd to me that you can't simply assign the number without converting to a string. Like: `CellValue = value` Doesn't OpenXML work that way?

Comment: @D_Bester Not really, [`CellValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.celltype.cellvalue%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property should be assigned a `CellValue` object. And `CellValue` class [doesn't have constructor that accept the number directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cellvalue.cellvalue%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks man. It works. I just took off my share string. I think it's the source where problem came.

Comment: @har07 Thanks. I'm seeing how that works. Essentially XML is text anyway then Excel interprets the text to build the spreadsheet for the user. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I followed the advices from the various posts and answers applying a style on the cell... no success.

Finally I found the origin of the problem and so the solution :

In my loop, I inserted all data in the same way i.e. using the `InsertSharedStringItem()` function.

If you insert a number in your spreadsheet like that, the cell formating will be useless and your number will not be considered as a number.

What you should do is to insert it "directly".

---

```
index =InsertSharedStringItem(myStringNumber, shareStringPart);
cell = InsertCellInWorksheet("A", 1, worksheetPart);
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(index.ToString());
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.SharedString);
cell.StyleIndex = _doubleStyleId;
```

will not work.

---

```
cell = InsertCellInWorksheet("A", 1, worksheetPart);
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(myStringNumber);
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
cell.StyleIndex = _doubleStyleId;
```

### is OK

with as Claies wrote :

```
Stylesheet styleSheet = workbook.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet; 
_doubleStyleId = createCellFormat(styleSheet, null,null, UInt32Value.FromUInt32(4));
```

the code for `createCellFormat()` can be found [here](http://www.lateral8.com/articles/2010/6/11/openxml-sdk-20-formatting-excel-values.aspx)

Comment: I edited my answer that is now more complete and fully relevant.

Comment: The link to createCellFormat has changed: http://www.lateral8.com/articles/openxml-format-excel-values.html

Answer (score 0):

OpenXML always creates a cell as Inline Text, and relies upon formatting to determine the correct display format within Excel.  Each number format in Excel corresponds to a unique code, and a style can be applied to the cell, the same way you might change the style from within Excel.

The [OpenXML Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) defines a series of codes which can be assigned without creating a custom StyleSheet.

The implied format for a double is 4 `#,##0.00`

so first you create the styleId:

```
Stylesheet styleSheet = workbook.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet; 
_doubleStyleId = createCellFormat(styleSheet, null, null, UInt32Value.FromUInt32(4));
```

then, set the styleId on the cell:

```
cell.StyleIndex = _doubleStyleId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Super late to this party but I ran into this problem and to me the solution was in the default stringifying of my local language, presumably the use of ',' as a decimal delimiter

```
Cell cell = new Cell() {
    DataType = CellValues.Number,
    CellValue = new CellValue(value.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"))) };
```

solved it for me.